# Create categorical variable/data subset with case matching

Tags: r, dplyr, match, subset, data-wrangling

I have a dataset like this:

```
structure(list(year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), 
    venue = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "O", "D"), HO = c("X", "Y", 
    "X", "Y", "W", "J"), AW = c("Y", "X", "W", "T", "T", "X")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to create a categorical variable that returns "yes" or "no".

```
structure(list(year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), 
    venue = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "O", "D"), HO = c("X", "Y", 
    "X", "Y", "W", "J"), AW = c("Y", "X", "W", "T", "T", "X"), 
    Cat = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As note, the first two rows are cases for "yes". These are the same in the attributes "year" and "venue", regardless of the order in "HO" and "AW".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first group your dataframe by row using `rowwise()`, then `paste` the `HO` and `AW` columns together. This step is to see which rows have the same `HO` and `AW` regardless of order. Then `group_by` the unique combination to categorise them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(paste_col = paste0(sort(str_split(paste0(HO, AW), "", simplify = T)), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  group_by(year, venue, paste_col) %>% 
  mutate(Cat = ifelse(n() > 1, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-paste_col)

# A tibble: 6 × 5
   year venue HO    AW    Cat  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1  2019 Z     X     Y     Yes  
2  2019 Z     Y     X     Yes  
3  2019 Z     X     W     No   
4  2019 Z     Y     T     No   
5  2019 O     W     T     No   
6  2019 D     J     X     No
```

Comment: It meets my demand.